# Promise { <pending> }

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
nuevoCliente: async (root, { input }) => {
  const existeCpf = await Cliente.findOne({ cpf: input.cpf });
  const existeCorreo = input.correos.map(async correo => {
       let prueba = await Cliente.findOne({ correos: [{ correo: correo.correo }] 
     });
  });
  console.log(existeCorreo);
  if(existeCorreo) {
    throw new Error("El correo ya existe intente con otro");
  }
}
```

El problema que tengo es que al intentar comprobar si existe correo en la base de datos me dice Promise {  }

Comment: Intenta añadir un `await` delante de `input.correos.map`. Ademas mira como funciona el metodo [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) porque si no tienes un `return` devuelve `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    nuevoCliente: async (root, { input }) => {
            const existeCpf = await Cliente.findOne({ cpf: input.cpf });
            const existeCorreo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                input.correos.map(correo => {
                    Cliente.findOne({ correos: [{ correo: correo.correo }] }, (error, datos) => {
                        if (error) reject(error);
                        else resolve(datos);
                    });
                });
            });
            if (existeCpf) throw new Error("El Cpf ya existe intente con otro");
            if (await existeCorreo) throw new Error("El correo ya existe intente con otro");
}
```

asi lo solucione espero que a otros le sirva y muchas gracias por sus contribuciones